# Facing no live responce on change of class of a div element on scrolling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have had read many answers here and tried to apply them too but it is not working in my case. I can't find what is going wrong with the following code (It is just an example of the problem I am facing):-

```js
 var header = $(".top-navigation");
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 100) {
    header.addClass("top-navigtion1").removeClass("top-navigation");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("top-navigation1").addClass("top-navigation";
  }
});
```

```css
 .container {
     width: 600px;
     height: 1500px;
     background-color: #000000;
    }
    .top-navigation {
     width: 600px;
     height: 100px;
     position: fixed;
     background-color:transparent;
     z-index: 1501 ;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .top-navigation1 {
     width: 500px;
     height: 100px;
     position:relative;
     background-color: 'blue';
     z-index: 1501;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-navigation">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're missing a `)`, also you've got a typo in one of the class names - `top-navigtion1`

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: this code works fine if you fixed the typo

Comment: I did remove almost all the errors and mistakes, but it is not supporting either (However its fiddle did work well, but it is supporting this code neither in Dreamweaver cs6 nor through notepad). @Marv actually my intention is to add this kind of script to my wordpress twentyseventeen theme, to apply different properties to my menu on scrolling event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this works for you. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/ayGwn/2912/)

Code

```
<header class="clearHeader"></header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Css:

```
.clearHeader{
 height: 200px; 
 background-color: rgba(107,107,107,0.66);
 position: fixed;
 top:200;
 width: 100%;
 }
 .darkHeader {height: 100px;}
 .wrapper {
  height:2000px;
 }
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
  }
  else {
         $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
  }
});
```

Comment: Even this code didn't work in my laptop. Is it missing something? or is my jquery framework is not up to date, I can't understand the problem.